# When Will Storage Requirements Exceed RAM in a System that Constantly Computes Higher Values and Stores Them on the Disk?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, math, recursion

I'm working on a project that can generate an infinite amount of numbers
`<More on this>`: [Threading Isues With Fixed Thread Pool and Large Number of Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430595/threading-isues-with-fixed-thread-pool-and-large-number-of-tasks) and I've been successful in solving the threading issues involved with it. Also, I've decided to store the results of the sequencer on the hard disk so I can compute more numbers (and make sure that they all converge to 1), I do this every time the `HashMap` that is storing the results reaches `400,000` (a reasonable size on my computer, about 1GB/8GB) key/value pairs, then load in the next `400,000`. Assuming that the values are `FinalSequencerReport`s, as the values get larger and larger tending towards `∞` the values stored should eventually exceed my RAM capacity, is there any way to get around this limitation (or even at what number I'll even encounter a situation where storing `400,000` instances will exceed my RAM capacity? Or a formula for any RAM capacity?) NOTE: inside the `FinalSequencerReport` class there is a `String`, it will always be empty.

Class being stored in the `HashMap<BigInteger, FinalSequencerReport<BigInteger>>`:

```
public static final class FinalSequencerReport<T extends Number> extends SequencerReport<T> implements Comparable<FinalSequencerReport<T>> {

    public static Comparator<? super FinalSequencerReport<? extends Number>> compareByInitialValue() {
        return (FinalSequencerReport<? extends Number> o1, FinalSequencerReport<? extends Number> o2)
                -> new BigInteger(o1.getInitialValue().toString()).compareTo(new BigInteger(o2.getInitialValue().toString()));
    }
    private final T initialValue;
    private final String finalFormattedString;

    public FinalSequencerReport(SequencerReport<T> finalReport, T initialValue) {
        super(finalReport.getResult(), finalReport.getIterations(), finalReport.getSequence());
        this.initialValue = initialValue;
        this.finalFormattedString = "Initial Value: "
                + getInitialValue() + "\nFinal Value: " + getResult() + "\nIterations:  "
                + getIterations() + "\nAlgebraic Sequence:\n" + getSequence();
    }

    public String getFinalFormattedString() {
        return this.finalFormattedString;
    }

    public Number getInitialValue() {
        return this.initialValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FinalSequencerReport<T> o) {
        return FinalSequencerReport.compareByInitialValue().compare(this, o);
    }
}

public static class SequencerReport<T extends Number> {

    private final T result, iterations;
    private final String sequence;

    public SequencerReport(T result, T iterations) {
        this(result, iterations, "");
    }

    public SequencerReport(T result, T iterations, String sequence) {
        this.result = result;
        this.iterations = iterations;
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }

    public T getIterations() {
        return this.iterations;
    }

    public String getSequence() {
        return this.sequence;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're computing all results sequentially, then there's no reason to use `BigInteger` as there's no change to leave the `long` range in a reasonable time. Note that `BigInteger` slows down the computation by a big factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to periodically [check the available HDD space](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-free-disk-space-in-java/), paired with a [RAM check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807848/351861) - i recommend checking the RAM much more often than the HDD.

If you want to estimate space-usage, you could [approximate the size of your objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368834/351861), but beware : as the internal representation of objects may change at any time you might get incorrect results, this is implementation-specific, object-sizes cant be accurately measured in java, AFAIK

Also note that the upper limit of available RAM always depends on your JVM-settings, the Oracle-JVM setting can be altered via `-Xmx`, possibles suffixes include `m` and `g`, example : `-Xmx2g` - dont fiddle with `-Xms` since it can seriously slow down everything if not produce weird crashes because you're effectively circumventing every JVM-optimization

free filesystem space & available RAM:

```
 /* Total number of processors or cores available to the JVM */
  System.out.println("Available processors (cores): " + 
  Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

  /* Total amount of free memory available to the JVM */
  System.out.println("Free memory (bytes): " + 
  Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());

  /* This will return Long.MAX_VALUE if there is no preset limit */
  long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
  /* Maximum amount of memory the JVM will attempt to use */
  System.out.println("Maximum memory (bytes): " + 
  (maxMemory == Long.MAX_VALUE ? "no limit" : maxMemory));

  /* Total memory currently in use by the JVM */
  System.out.println("Total memory (bytes): " + 
  Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());

  /* Get a list of all filesystem roots on this system */
  File[] roots = File.listRoots();

  /* For each filesystem root, print some info */
  for (File root : roots) {
    System.out.println("File system root: " + root.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Total space (bytes): " + root.getTotalSpace());
    System.out.println("Free space (bytes): " + root.getFreeSpace());
    System.out.println("Usable space (bytes): " + root.getUsableSpace());
  }
```

object size approximation :

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}

public class C {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(new C()));
    }
}
```